# How should I version control bash scripts that must be kept separate from my projects repository?

Tags: version-control

A class in my project needs some bash scripts and a program that is compiled from source. I consider them to be dependencies, so I looked into using Maven and Artifactory to host the files and download them. However, I've found that Artifactory doesn't seem to allow script files (my coworkers assure me that it only works for .jar files with our current setup).

What is the best way to achieve the hosting and download of these files? Is it my only choice to keep another git repository?

Comment: Based on what you've stated and what you indicate to be the situation, then it does sound like another Git repository is the solution. Is there a reason that appears to be an issue to you, and that you want to seek alternatives for? I an failing to grasp why this setup would be an issue, but I may be missing something.

Comment: The program that is needed for my class is really an artifact, I think my other team members shouldn't bother with compiling it. So I looked into artifact management and found that we already use Arttifactory, but it doesn't seem to support anything besides a .jar file.